# Оптимизация решения с возрастом

Tags: kotlin, инспекция-кода

Задача следующая:

> Для заданного 0 < n < 200, рассматриваемого как возраст человека, вернуть строку вида: «21 год», «32 года», «12 лет».

Написал что то подобное:

```
fun ageDescription(age: Int): String {
    return when {
        age / 10 % 10 == 1 -> "$age лет"
        age % 10 == 1 -> "$age год"
        age / 10 % 10 == 9 -> "$age лет"
        else -> "$age года"
    }
}
```

Тесты проходят успешно, а вот и они кстати говоря:

```
@Test
fun ageDescription() {
    assertEquals("1 год", ageDescription(1))
    assertEquals("21 год", ageDescription(21))
    assertEquals("132 года", ageDescription(132))
    assertEquals("12 лет", ageDescription(12))
    assertEquals("111 лет", ageDescription(111))
    assertEquals("199 лет", ageDescription(199))
}
```

Возможно ли упросить данное решение? А то как будто бы строка лишняя :`age / 10 % 10 == 9 -> "$age лет"`

P.S. Движуха с plurals(few, many, other, etc..), которая в Android не подходит:)

Comment: а 38 тоже года?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня 5 условий получается по-любому.

**Java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        System.out.println(ageDescription(i));
    }
}

private static String ageDescription(int age) {
    if (age < 1) return null;
    int lastDigit = age % 10;
    String ageStr = "";
    if (age - lastDigit == 10 || age - lastDigit == 110) {
        ageStr = " лет"; // 10 - 19 лет || 110 - 119 лет
    } else if (lastDigit == 0) {
        ageStr = " лет";
    } else if (lastDigit == 1) {
        ageStr = " год";
    } else if (lastDigit <= 4) {
        ageStr = " года";
    } else {
        ageStr = " лет";
    }
    return age + ageStr;
}
```

Comment: Да, теперь вроде гуд)
но при всём при этом, врядли это смахивает на оптимизацию, даже если конвертнуть на kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

Вот на любой возраст:

```
fun ageDescription(age: Int): String =
    when (age % 100) {
        in 11..14 -> "$age лет"
        else -> when (age % 10) {
            1 -> "$age год"
            in 2..4 -> "$age года"
            else -> "$age лет"
        }
    }
```

Или еще проще:

```
fun ageDescription(age: Int): String =
        when {
            age % 100 in 11..14 -> "$age лет"
            age % 10 == 1 -> "$age год"
            age % 10 in 2..4 -> "$age года"
            else -> "$age лет"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать ветку else для фильтрафии значений не выполняющих условие: 0 < age, то этот алгоритм для вас:

```
fun ageDescription(age: Int): String {
    return when {
        age % 10 == 1 && age % 100 != 11 -> "$age год"
        age % 10 in 5..10 || age % 100 in 11..14 -> "$age лет"
        age % 10 in 2..4 -> "$age года"
        else -> "Некорректные данные"
    }
}
```